# Возможности и назначение языка Perl

Tags: perl

Доброго времени суток! Хотелось бы узнать стоит ли изучать Perl. Каковы его функциональные возможности, применение и назначение?

Comment: [Вот здесь](http://www.opennet.ru/openforum/vsluhforumID9/7742.html#1) очень много народа сравнивают перл и питон.

Comment: Ещё в прошлом тысячелетии видел питоновский сайт, у которого на страничке был анимированный gif: стоит верблюд по центру, слева вылетает зелёный змей, сшибает скотину набок и вышибает с картинки.

Comment: @alexlz, в общем, так оно и есть. Но в некоторых областях он продолжает держать позиции. И некоторые крупные конторы, типа Яндекс или Мейл.ру постоянно имеют вакансии для перловых программистов.

Но если нет особой необходимости, я бы не посоветовал бы его для изучения в первой очереди.

Comment: Меня в перле больше всего смущает обилие очень хитро написанных скриптов с мощными регулярными выражениями (и без комментариев, как это работает). 

Впечатление, что это конкурс "скилломерии".

Comment: Ну это да. В мире перла считается, чем замысловатее написан скрипт, тем лучше.)))

Comment: @avp ну их-то регэкспы сейчас везде. У перла других вывихов через край. Взять хотя бы две сосуществующие системы видимости: лексикографическая (если не переврал) и пакетная. Но читать перловые скрипты нелегко. Особенно без ключиков `-w` и `use strict;` @mikillskegg раз были созданы, сейчас поддерживаются и развиваются, и будут жить (и судьба yahoo store им не грозит). Но по моему личному убеждению, таких фокусов лучше больше не делать. Лучше всёже что-нибудь менее error-prone.

Answer (score 6):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl

По мне, так это очень удобный и простой язык. Мой любимый )))

Comment: А почему у перла разное отношение к переменной `$l` и переменной `$a`? Или какое значение будет в арифметическом выражени нулём, а в логическом -- истиной. (-w, разумеется должен быть)

Comment: Ещё и $b. Дело в том, что переменные а и б используются Перлом при сортировке, соответственно, использовать их в программе для чего-то другого не рекомендуется, но можно.
Арифметическим нулём будет 0, как это не странно.
В логическом любое значение отличное от 0 или undefа.

Comment: На первый вопрос ответ правильный. Второй, перефразирую. Подставить значение переменной $c, чтобы скрипт выдал результат 1

      perl -we '$c=<сюда подставить>; if ($c) {print 1+$c}'

Comment: Интересно, как в этом окошке так красиво код выделить? ))

    perl -we '$c=0; if (defined $c) {print 1+$c}'

Comment: Отступы в начале строки и пустые строки вокруг (по крайней мере перед).

    perl -we '$c=q{0E1}; if ($c) {print 1+$c}'
    # или
    perl -we '$c=q{0E1}; print 1+$c if $c'

Показатель степени десятки может быть любым. Кажись использовалось где-то в DBI::что-то-там. Если 0E0 -- запрос выполнен, но результат -- 0 строк. А если undef -- облом запроса.

@mikilskegg Что гыгы? Эволюция или gnuhello (http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/hello.pdf)? А эволюция прикольней у программиста на хаскеле.

Answer (score 4):

В настоящее время широко используется для обработки больших объемов текстовой информации, собственно для чего и был создан. Это и определяет сферу его популярности. Кроме всего прочего, туда входит такая серьезная наука как биоинформатика - наука об анализе последовательностей нуклеиновых кислот и пептидов.

Answer (score 4):

Perl - это "мощный, гибкий, безопасный и современный" язык высокого уровня, который используется в самых различных областях - от парсинга текстовой информации до разработки графических и мультимедиа-приложений.

Отлично справляется с обработкой различного типа данных, поэтому часто используется при написании различного вида парсеров и ботов. Может использоваться для задач системного администрирования.

Одной из современных "ниш" для языка Perl стала веб-разработка. На нём написано немало веб-фреймворков - как [микрофреймворков](http://perldancer.org/), так и полнофункциональных [MVC-фреймворков](http://www.catalystframework.org/). Многие компании разрабатывают свои движки на языке Perl - это регистраторы доменных имён и хостинг-провайдеры, поисковые системы, SEO-компании, медиакомпании, разработчики онлайн-игр и т.д.

В последние годы язык Perl переживает свой "ренессанс", своего рода возрождение - очень многое было доработано как в самом языке (к примеру, появилась наиболее полная из всех языков поддержка Unicode), так и в сторонних модулях: написаны фреймворки для эффективной [объектно-ориентированной разработки](http://moose.iinteractive.com/), [асинхронного программирования](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent), удобные [ORM](http://www.dbix-class.org/),  и многое, многое другое. Как выразился недавно один комментатор блога о Perl:"This is not your Daddy's Perl" - "Это не тот Perl, на котором программировал твой папочка" :) Это [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/).

У языка Perl довольно активное комьюнити, которое поддерживает и развивает его. Ежегодно по всему миру проводятся десятки конференций YAPC (Yet Another Perl Conference), воркшопов и технических, а также нетехнических встреч, посвящённых Perl - в том числе и [в России](http://perlrussia.ru/) (зачастую с участием заграничных гостей). Участие в таких мероприятиях как правило бесплатное.

Кстати, одна из таких конференций будет проводиться совсем скоро, 12-13 мая, в Киеве. Если есть время, возможность и интерес к языку Perl, весьма рекомендую прийти послушать доклады и пообщаться с людьми, использующими этот язык в повседневной жизни.
Участие в конференции бесплатное, нужно только зарегистрироваться и подать заявку на участие [на сайте конференции](http://perlmova.org/yr2012/).

Comment: "безопасный и современный"? Да уж... А безопасный -- как пулемёт у Попандопуло ("Свадьба в Малиновке") -- "по своим стреляет"?

>При серьёзных разработках оказывает положительное влияние на здоровье, повышая уровень адреналина в крови

Comment: Отвечая на все Ваши комментарии.

По-моему у Вас голова забита неправильным представлением о языке, и Вы понятия не имеете, как на нём пишут программы. Не скрипты-однострочники, а программные системы с мегабайтами кода.

В каждой уважающей себя компании существуют стандарты кодирования и оформления кода, а в идеале и peer-to-peer code review, так что написать нечитаемый код на Perl Вам просто не позволят.

Perl *позволяет* писать как нечитаемые, так и вполне читаемые программы. Выбор всегда за программистом.

И если он предпочитает писать нечитаемый код - это уже многое о нём говорит ;)

Comment: Да, я действительно не представляю, как на нём пишут программные системы с мегабайтами кода. С сотнями (возможно небольшими тысячами) строк неграмотного кода я скрипты видел. Зрелище не для слабонервных. 

Возможно пишут и большие. Вопрос -- зачем? Можно и лопатой деревья рубить, только пила/топор как-то удобнее.

Comment: Так в том и дело, что ничего удобнее перла лично я не встречал. Хотя профессионально использую достаточно большое количество языков (но любые отступления от перла бывают только по одной причине - требование заказчика).

Answer (score 4):

Perl даёт всё, что бы писать изящный и выразительный код.
Мультипарадигменный, модифицируемый,  подстраиваемый под любую модель разработки.
P.S. и конечно же не стоит забывать, что у хороших perl программистов всегда будет интересная и высокооплачиваемая работа.

Comment: Как и у любых других программистов ;D

Comment: Ну что Вы, не у любых, а только у хороших(и да, язык тут не главное).

А на счёт мощности языка и его изменчивости... посмотрите на подмножество Acme::* ( https://metacpan.org/search?q=Acme%3A%3A )

https://metacpan.org/module/Acme::Morse
https://metacpan.org/module/Acme::Ukrop
https://metacpan.org/module/Acme::Pythonic
Acme::Brainfuck, Acme::Bleach и ещё горы всего.
Если у перловиков есть время писать такие странные вещи, то всё, что им нужно для работы, они уже написали.

Answer (score 4):

В последнее время Perl  очень бурно развивается. Появились очень качественные веб-фреймворки, такие как [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/), [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/). Появился полностью асинхронный веб-фреймворк [Tatsumaki](https://metacpan.org/module/Tatsumaki), который по производительности может поспорить с Node.js. Так что для разработки веб-приложений Perl подходит как нельзя лучше. А если учесть, что В Perl есть одна из самых лучших систем тестирования, то разработка методом TDD ( Test Driven Development ) становится одним сплошным удовольствием, и программы получаются очень качественные.

Perl - это умный язык. Его разрабатывал лингвист по профессии. Поэтому Perl - это набор базовых кирпичиков, из которых можно построить красивое здание Вашего веб-проекта. Любые готовые части здания можно найти на [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) или новом поисковике [METACPAN](https://metacpan.org/). Это позволяет построить здание веб-проекта с максимально высокой скоростью.

В общем, выбирая язык программирования Perl, Вы однозначно выигрываете.

Comment: А что обожествление таких святых качеств, как лень, гордыня и нетерпение, уже в прошлом. Л.Волл изменил себе?

Comment: Все это реализуется в Perl6 ))

Answer (score 3):

Perl весьма лаконичный, живой, изящный и одновременно CPAN-термоядерный. В нём сочетаются разные традиции и нет осуждения. Он даёт спокойствие и находит гармонию. Остальные --- блеклая тень и суета.

Comment: Перл очень хорош для однострочников. При увеличении длины скрипта его преимущества быстро превращаются в недостатки.

Comment: Без лишних сущностей можно так:
$_ = 'World';
say /^World$/ ? 'Hello' : 'Bye', ", $_!";

# или
say qw{Bye Hello}[/^World$/+0], ", $_!";

Comment: А теперь объясните мне, почему у меня это не работает? (желательно без наводящих вопросов). Сможете, уважаемый говорун?

Comment: Прям так и хочется после этого ответа произнести: In saecula saeculorum.

Comment: Согласен, Пусть уважаемый говорун объяснит. Позовите говоруна!
От себя могу добавить `use feature qw( say );`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл. Конечно ---
In saecula saeculorum 
:)

Comment: Говорун -- от *говорить* (say). И проблема была, разумеется, в отсутствии use feature.

Answer (score 2):

Перл позволяет сфокусироваться на проблеме, а не на ее реализации, работает везде, никогда не ломал обратную совместимость и не собирается. 
Очень хороший язык для новичков: можно писать полноценные работающие программы с первого дня и изучать новые функции постепенно. Пример:

```
my $name = "World";

if ($name eq 'World') {
    print "Hello, $name\n";
} else {
    print "Bye, $name\n";
}
```

Comment: большенство современных языков могут тоже самое и что?

Comment: А на питоне?

     name = 'World'
     if name == 'World': print ('Hello, %s\n' % name)
     else : print ('Bye, %s\n' % name)

Comment: мде... Пример - печаль

Comment: А что в примере показать?
Регулярные выражения в условиях:

    if ($name =~ /^(World|Something)$/) {
        print "Hello, $1\n";
    }

Регулярные выражения как функция:

    print "Hello, ", $name =~ /^(World|Something)$/;

Массивы, хэши, скаляры:

    my @array = (1, 2, 3);
    my %hash = (a => 1, b => 2);
    my $scalar = 1;

Comment: вот, это уже интересней, хотя тоже в других я зыках реализуется=)

Answer (score 1):

На perl легко и быстро написать:

- бота, паука.
- систему обработки террабайтов текста и html.
- окошечное приложение под linux(qt,gtk).
- web интерфейс(Rose::DB +HTML::Template + fastcgi), который не будет падать от 1000 одновременных соединений.
- однострочники для повседневых задач(`cat access.log|perl -le 'split,$h{$_[0]}++ for <>; $,="\n"; print map{"$_ $h{$_}"} sort{$h{$a}<=>$h{$b}}keys %h'|tail`)
- клиент для любого веб и не только сервиса.
- и многое другое.

Comment: Быстро ничего не получится...

Comment: Это мой опыт, у тебя может и не получится - у меня получилось.

Comment: Мой опыт в этой сфере тоже далеко не мал =) Тем не менее, качественного бота быстро написать не получится. Если вы заявляете, что сумеете написать бота быстро, то это говорит о низком качестве ваших ботов.

Answer (score 1):

Последний пример я бы переписал так:

```
my $name = 'World';
my $greet = $name eq 'World' ? 'Hello' : 'Bye';
say $greet . ',' . $name;
```

А помимо обработки текста, perl очень хорош для системного программирования под unix like OS. На нем пишутся различные системы мониторинга сетей, оборудования и т.п. И в этой сфере он гораздо более востребованный нежели С/С++, потому что скорость разработки на нем в разы быстрей.

Comment: Чего уж так скромно-то?

     my $name=World;
     print qw{Hello Bye}[$name != World], q{, }, $name, qq{!\n};

Всё равно -- бяка.

Comment: Ну я привел пример читаемости, а вы - нечитаемости. Принцип TIMTOWTDI

Comment: И что же тут нечитаемого? Просто перл -- такой язык. Сложный. Чтобы читать написанные на нём скрипты, надо знать много всяких мелочей. Из ничетаемого тут что: print? операции q, qq, qw? операция `!=`? операция индексации? Всё достаточно просто, но прочитать без подготовки (и не 5-15 минут) вряд ли кто из незнакомых с перлом сможет. Языка такая. (Кстати, сишный тернаный условный оператор "?:" у незнакомых с ним тоже шок вызывает).

Comment: Нет не надо говорить что "perl такой язык сложный". Это не правда. "perl позволяет делать простые вещи просто, а сложные делает возможными" (c) Larry Wall.

Comment: Почему я должен верить всему, что пишет Larry Wall? Это его детище, не будет же он его ругать.

Comment: По поводу высказывания Ларри. Простые вещи на то и простые. Еще бы не хватало, чтобы Хеловорд занимал несколько страниц. А то, что сложные вещи делаются возможными - очень хитрое высказывание. Возможно - не значит просто. Все на свете можно выразить на ассемблере, но это не значить, что сделать это просто.

Перл - язык очень хитрый. Простым он является на уровне чуть сложнее упомянутого Хеловорда. Далее следует куча всяких тонкостей и хитростей.

Comment: Хеловорд, говорите? Ну-ну. Смотреть сюда: http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html, раздел "Master Programmer"

Ещё можно Gnu Hello посмотреть. Тоже впечатляет.

Comment: Гыгы. Смешно. Я не имел в виду извращения, а нормальное использование языка. А так, это еще не предел...

Comment: Хакер только неаккуратный. Так будет без warning-ов :

    #define S "Hello, world.\n"
    int main(){ return (write(1,S,sizeof(S)-1) == sizeof(S)-1 ? 0 : 1);}

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не начинайте изучать Perl, так как спрос на программистов Perl за предыдущий год упал почти в 2 раза! Точно такая же картина с программистами PHP... Лучше начните изучать Ruby, Ruby на рельсах или Python+Django. Спрос на этих программистов вырос почти в два раза! Несмотря на то, что Perl довольно мощный и гибкий язык, изучить его можно лишь для саморазвития, но не для профессиональной деятельности, так как он постепенно гибнет на глазах. Ему на смену идут совершенно новые решения.

Comment: "Точно такая же картина с программистами PHP" - пруф будет? Лично я обладаю иной информацией

Ага и ruby программисты востребованы :D

Хотя с тем, что Perl умирает - согласен

Comment: А вот в февральском рейтинге языков программирования, публикуемых компанией Tiobe, [смотрел здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137833/) **perl** слегка поднялся.

Так где спрос упал (и когда он высоким был) ?

Comment: Ну раз спрос упала в два раза, значит он был когда-то в два раза выше =). На самом деле, квалифицированные разработчики PHP/Perl с опытом работы от 10 лет по-прежнему получают порядка 150000 рублей, но спрос на эти языки падает с каждым месяцем. Например, в два раза спрос упал с 1 сентября 2011 по 1 декабря 2011.

Comment: Кстати, исходя из приведенного вами списка популярности языков, на Python спрос упал почти на 4% ! Интересно с чем это может быть связано?