# Стоить ли учить perl 5?

Tags: perl

Стоить ли учить perl 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю однозначно стоит, т.к. это современный язык, который активно развивается, для веб-разработки можете посмотреть в сторону Plack/PSGI, Mojolicious, Dancer/Dancer2, Kelp. 
На русском языке развивается журнал о современном Perl: http://pragmaticperl.com/
Еще несколько ссылок на русском:

- http://perltrap.com/ru/
- http://ru.perlmaven.com/
- https://perljobs.ru/
- http://perldancer.ru/home
- http://dev-lab.info/
- http://alpha6.ru/
- http://dev.perltuts.com/
- https://github.com/timurn/modern_perl_book/tree/russian_translation/translation/ru/sections

Comment: К сожалению, как раз журнал развиваться перестал. И то ли в том самом 2015-м, то ли в 2016-м году

Answer (score 2):

Ну учить можно стихотворения. А понимать можно начинать. 
Но опять же, смотря для чего он вам. Если вы живете в nix* то он вам как родной станет, если в сторону веб-программинга - тут надо думать.
Язык лишь средство, смотря в какой области применять будете.

Comment: В сторону веб-программирования, особенно под юниксоподобными ОС — тоже хорошо идёт, даже в 2018 году.

Answer (score 1):

Дубль.

[Возможности и назначение языка Perl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/97019/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-perl)

ЗЫ. Однозначно стоит, но без опыта трудно куда-нибудь устроиться.

Answer (score 1):

Тут не столько важна "цифра", сколько само название технологии - "Perl". Если говорить кратко, то нет, не стоит учить Perl сейчас( ни первый, ни пятый, ни десятый ). Эта технология начала умирать на 8 лет раньше PHP, а PHP сейчас хоть и является самым распространенным языком для разработки веб приложений, но все же это ему особо не помогает не умирать.

Также важно то, где вы собираетесь использовать технологию. Если для разработки "инновационных" решений, то, определенно, учить его, опять же, нет смысла. Если же для себя( в качестве экзотики, например, как сейчас становится "модно" разбираться в древних вещах типа ADA или вещах без смысла, как BrainFuck  ), то, пожалуйста : многому можно научиться и многое понять, изучая Perl. Например, разобраться в том, как в общем работают скриптовые языки.

Сейчас хоть и есть сообщества Perl-программистов и даже готовится Perl 6. Но это вовсе не делает его "мейнстримовым" и передовым языком. Лучше потратить время на что-то более серьёзное вроде Java, Python или на тот же PHP.

Comment: А чем python или java лучше perl?

Comment: @Aydar2015, они более распространены  
(хотя, я бы не стал сравнивать perl с Java, из перечисленных языков (IMHO) можно сопоставлять с Python и PHP).

О сравнении языков можете [полюбопытствовать здесь](https://www.openhub.net/languages/compare?commit=Update&l0=c&l1=cpp&l2=java&l3=perl&l4=php&l5=python&l6=-1&measure=commits&percent=true)

Comment: Питон или Ява не лучше Перла и не хуже — они другие.
Питон и Руби «лучше» тем, что там не так сильно, как в Перле, нужны фигурные скобки ну и не нужны символы, указывающие тип переменной. Ну и плюс все они (особенно PHP) сейчас шире распространились в области веб-технологий, чем Перл.
Перл явно повлиял на PHP, Python и Ruby, так что знакомство с ним полезно хотя бы потому, что проще будет разобраться с другими языками.

Answer (score 1):

Цифра в вопросе как бы намекает, что вы выбираете между Perl 5 и Perl 6.

Если это так, то для работы, выполнения реальных задач, все же стоит пока учить Perl 5.

Perl 6 можно учить потому, что в нем очень много новых фишек - многие задачи можно решить более удобными методами, чем на других языках (том же Perl 5), и эти методы встроены напрямую в язык. Изучение самого этого языка способно поднять ваш общий уровень как программиста.

Хотя если вам в компании разрешают применять подобные инновации, можете попробовать Perl 6 и для реальных небольших проектов в продакшене. Однако имейте в виду, что по быстродействию Perl 6 пока не на высоте, хотя и постоянно улучшается в этом плане, как и в других (за последний год, кстати, сильно вырос - и по фишкам тоже).
Уже через неделю Ларри объявит, что язык готов для использования в продакшене: https://fosdem.org/2015/schedule/event/get_ready_to_party/

Comment: Ничего хорошего в Perl 6 я не нашел, это просто тупик.

Comment: 6 perl - это площадка по обкатке новых мыслей. Хорошие идеи постепенно переползают в perl 5. Есть такая мысль, что когда то в будущем пятая версия догонит шестую.

Comment: Хорошо бы, а то в 5-ю добавят что-то, потом передумают и сделают по другому, это напрягает.

Comment: из всего, что "отменили" на протяжении 5.8 - 5.20 - так это оператор `~~` и `switch`. Но, думаю, Вы о них и не знали...:)

Comment: А как же функция keys? Не слыхали про такую?)))

Comment: а что же с ней случилось? Работает как и раньше. Или о Вы рандомизации хеша?

Comment: Я про keys $hash_ref - так было. Теперь решили делать так: keys $hash_ref->%*
И ругаются, что теперь всё экспериментальное. Причём, на ~~ тоже.
Про ~~ вообще загнули (экспериментальная), должна же в языке быть функция поиска элемента в массиве.

Comment: по поводу `~~`. Этот оператор забанили не даром. Он нарушает концепцию. (в перл оператор определяет тип операндов. сравните `eq` и `==`). Но есть More::Utils. Там все есть.

А вот с keys - я никогда не пользовался ситуацией, когда на вход попадает ссылка. Всегда явно разыменовываю. А синтаксис вида ` $hash_ref->%*` - это вроде 6 перл.